# WPF Toolbar line wrapping

Tags: wpf, toolbar, word-wrap

I have a WPF application with a ToolBarTray composed of a few ToolBar with tons of buttons. The only thing I want is for them to always be visible, no matter the size of the window.

```
<ToolBarTray>
    <ToolBar OverflowMode="Never">
        <userControls:SearchUserControl x:Name="SearchControl" />
    </ToolBar>
    <ToolBar ItemsSource="{Binding CommonCommands}" OverflowMode="Never"/>
    <ToolBar ItemsSource="{Binding Type1Commands}" OverflowMode="Never"/>
    <ToolBar ItemsSource="{Binding Type2Commands}" OverflowMode="Never" />
    <ToolBar ItemsSource="{Binding Type3Commands}" OverflowMode="Never" />
</ToolBarTray>
```

I set OverflowMode="Never" to get rid of the little arrow on the right where buttons goes when there's not enough space since I always want all buttons visible. My "commands" list are RoutedCommand with a DataTemplate to show up as a button, but it react the same whatever I use.

If I put the ToolBarTray inside a StackPanel, their buttons/toolbars just continue past the window size. If I put the ToolBarTray inside a WrapPanel, instead of wrapping it hide the buttons completely (only the toolbar grip remains).

The comportment I would love to achieve is for toolbars to change their Band property dynamically so that if there's no space available, the toolbar switch to the second band (row) instead of hiding the buttons in their overflow panel.

Comment: Can you limit the minimum with of the window to the actualWidth of the ToolBarTray?

Comment: That's not really a possibility since the full width of the toolbar is currently 1721 pixels wide with over 50 buttons and will keep growing. Works fine on a 1080p display, but anything lower than that need to be split on two bands (rows) (which is what we have forced currently, and look strange on 1080p displays, and still crop buttons if the window is not fullscreen).

Answer (score 3):

Wrapping a ToolBar's content is not easy, but of course it is possible. The point is that the standard `ToolBar` control wants a `TemplatePart` called "PART_ToolBarPanel", whose type must be `ToolBarPanel`. The ToolBarPanel inherits from `StackPanel`, but for achieving your target, you should use a `WrapPanel`.
So since the ToolBarPanel inherits from StackPanel, it cannot inherit at the same time from WrapPanel.

My idea is to extend the ToolBarPanel and to *disguise* it so it looks like a WrapPanel. First of all let's see the code of our ToolBarPanel (I used ILSpy in order to retrive the WrapPanel code behavior):

```
public class ToolBarPanel : System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.ToolBarPanel
{
    private struct UVSize
    {
        internal double U;
        internal double V;
        private Orientation _orientation;
        internal double Width
        {
            get
            {
                if (this._orientation != Orientation.Horizontal)
                {
                    return this.V;
                }
                return this.U;
            }
            set
            {
                if (this._orientation == Orientation.Horizontal)
                {
                    this.U = value;
                    return;
                }
                this.V = value;
            }
        }
        internal double Height
        {
            get
            {
                if (this._orientation != Orientation.Horizontal)
                {
                    return this.U;
                }
                return this.V;
            }
            set
            {
                if (this._orientation == Orientation.Horizontal)
                {
                    this.V = value;
                    return;
                }
                this.U = value;
            }
        }
        internal UVSize(Orientation orientation, double width, double height)
        {
            this.U = (this.V = 0.0);
            this._orientation = orientation;
            this.Width = width;
            this.Height = height;
        }
        internal UVSize(Orientation orientation)
        {
            this.U = (this.V = 0.0);
            this._orientation = orientation;
        }
    }

    private static int _itemWidth = 80;
    private static int _itemHeight = 30;

    private static bool IsWidthHeightValid(object value)
    {
        double num = (double)value;
        return DoubleUtil.IsNaN(num) || (num >= 0.0 && !double.IsPositiveInfinity(num));
    }

    protected override Size ArrangeOverride(Size finalSize)
    {
        int num = 0;
        double itemWidth = _itemWidth;
        double itemHeight = _itemHeight;
        double num2 = 0.0;
        double itemU = (this.Orientation == Orientation.Horizontal) ? itemWidth : itemHeight;
        ToolBarPanel.UVSize uVSize = new ToolBarPanel.UVSize(this.Orientation);
        ToolBarPanel.UVSize uVSize2 = new ToolBarPanel.UVSize(this.Orientation, finalSize.Width, finalSize.Height);
        bool flag = !DoubleUtil.IsNaN(itemWidth);
        bool flag2 = !DoubleUtil.IsNaN(itemHeight);
        bool useItemU = (this.Orientation == Orientation.Horizontal) ? flag : flag2;
        UIElementCollection internalChildren = base.InternalChildren;
        int i = 0;
        int count = internalChildren.Count;
        while (i < count)
        {
            UIElement uIElement = internalChildren[i];
            if (uIElement != null)
            {
                ToolBarPanel.UVSize uVSize3 = new ToolBarPanel.UVSize(this.Orientation, flag ? itemWidth : uIElement.DesiredSize.Width, flag2 ? itemHeight : uIElement.DesiredSize.Height);
                if (DoubleUtil.GreaterThan(uVSize.U + uVSize3.U, uVSize2.U))
                {
                    this.ArrangeLine(num2, uVSize.V, num, i, useItemU, itemU);
                    num2 += uVSize.V;
                    uVSize = uVSize3;
                    if (DoubleUtil.GreaterThan(uVSize3.U, uVSize2.U))
                    {
                        this.ArrangeLine(num2, uVSize3.V, i, ++i, useItemU, itemU);
                        num2 += uVSize3.V;
                        uVSize = new ToolBarPanel.UVSize(this.Orientation);
                    }
                    num = i;
                }
                else
                {
                    uVSize.U += uVSize3.U;
                    uVSize.V = Math.Max(uVSize3.V, uVSize.V);
                }
            }
            i++;
        }
        if (num < internalChildren.Count)
        {
            this.ArrangeLine(num2, uVSize.V, num, internalChildren.Count, useItemU, itemU);
        }
        return finalSize;
    }

    private void ArrangeLine(double v, double lineV, int start, int end, bool useItemU, double itemU)
    {
        double num = 0.0;
        bool flag = this.Orientation == Orientation.Horizontal;
        UIElementCollection internalChildren = base.InternalChildren;
        for (int i = start; i < end; i++)
        {
            UIElement uIElement = internalChildren[i];
            if (uIElement != null)
            {
                ToolBarPanel.UVSize uVSize = new ToolBarPanel.UVSize(this.Orientation, uIElement.DesiredSize.Width, uIElement.DesiredSize.Height);
                double num2 = useItemU ? itemU : uVSize.U;
                uIElement.Arrange(new Rect(flag ? num : v, flag ? v : num, flag ? num2 : lineV, flag ? lineV : num2));
                num += num2;
            }
        }
    }

    protected override Size MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
    {
        ToolBarPanel.UVSize uVSize = new ToolBarPanel.UVSize(this.Orientation);
        ToolBarPanel.UVSize uVSize2 = new ToolBarPanel.UVSize(this.Orientation);
        ToolBarPanel.UVSize uVSize3 = new ToolBarPanel.UVSize(this.Orientation, constraint.Width, constraint.Height);
        double itemWidth = _itemWidth;
        double itemHeight = _itemHeight;
        bool flag = !DoubleUtil.IsNaN(itemWidth);
        bool flag2 = !DoubleUtil.IsNaN(itemHeight);
        Size availableSize = new Size(flag ? itemWidth : constraint.Width, flag2 ? itemHeight : constraint.Height);
        UIElementCollection internalChildren = base.InternalChildren;
        int i = 0;
        int count = internalChildren.Count;
        while (i < count)
        {
            UIElement uIElement = internalChildren[i];
            if (uIElement != null)
            {
                uIElement.Measure(availableSize);
                ToolBarPanel.UVSize uVSize4 = new ToolBarPanel.UVSize(this.Orientation, flag ? itemWidth : uIElement.DesiredSize.Width, flag2 ? itemHeight : uIElement.DesiredSize.Height);
                if (DoubleUtil.GreaterThan(uVSize.U + uVSize4.U, uVSize3.U))
                {
                    uVSize2.U = Math.Max(uVSize.U, uVSize2.U);
                    uVSize2.V += uVSize.V;
                    uVSize = uVSize4;
                    if (DoubleUtil.GreaterThan(uVSize4.U, uVSize3.U))
                    {
                        uVSize2.U = Math.Max(uVSize4.U, uVSize2.U);
                        uVSize2.V += uVSize4.V;
                        uVSize = new ToolBarPanel.UVSize(this.Orientation);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    uVSize.U += uVSize4.U;
                    uVSize.V = Math.Max(uVSize4.V, uVSize.V);
                }
            }
            i++;
        }
        uVSize2.U = Math.Max(uVSize.U, uVSize2.U);
        uVSize2.V += uVSize.V;
        return new Size(uVSize2.Width, uVSize2.Height);
    }
}
```

Just for the purpose of this sample, I used two static variables (`_itemWidth` and `_itemHeight`) to define the WrapPanel item size. Anyway they should be replaced with two dependecy properties. Moreover the extended ToolBar does not handle the Orientation changes (just use ILSpy to adapt it).

In order to make this code work, I added the `DoubleUtil` class too:

```
public static class DoubleUtil
{
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
    private struct NanUnion
    {
        [FieldOffset(0)]
        internal double DoubleValue;
        [FieldOffset(0)]
        internal ulong UintValue;
    }
    internal const double DBL_EPSILON = 2.2204460492503131E-16;
    internal const float FLT_MIN = 1.17549435E-38f;
    public static bool AreClose(double value1, double value2)
    {
        if (value1 == value2)
        {
            return true;
        }
        double num = (Math.Abs(value1) + Math.Abs(value2) + 10.0) * 2.2204460492503131E-16;
        double num2 = value1 - value2;
        return -num < num2 && num > num2;
    }
    public static bool LessThan(double value1, double value2)
    {
        return value1 < value2 && !DoubleUtil.AreClose(value1, value2);
    }
    public static bool GreaterThan(double value1, double value2)
    {
        return value1 > value2 && !DoubleUtil.AreClose(value1, value2);
    }
    public static bool LessThanOrClose(double value1, double value2)
    {
        return value1 < value2 || DoubleUtil.AreClose(value1, value2);
    }
    public static bool GreaterThanOrClose(double value1, double value2)
    {
        return value1 > value2 || DoubleUtil.AreClose(value1, value2);
    }
    public static bool IsOne(double value)
    {
        return Math.Abs(value - 1.0) < 2.2204460492503131E-15;
    }
    public static bool IsZero(double value)
    {
        return Math.Abs(value) < 2.2204460492503131E-15;
    }
    public static bool AreClose(Point point1, Point point2)
    {
        return DoubleUtil.AreClose(point1.X, point2.X) && DoubleUtil.AreClose(point1.Y, point2.Y);
    }
    public static bool AreClose(Size size1, Size size2)
    {
        return DoubleUtil.AreClose(size1.Width, size2.Width) && DoubleUtil.AreClose(size1.Height, size2.Height);
    }
    public static bool AreClose(Vector vector1, Vector vector2)
    {
        return DoubleUtil.AreClose(vector1.X, vector2.X) && DoubleUtil.AreClose(vector1.Y, vector2.Y);
    }
    public static bool AreClose(Rect rect1, Rect rect2)
    {
        if (rect1.IsEmpty)
        {
            return rect2.IsEmpty;
        }
        return !rect2.IsEmpty && DoubleUtil.AreClose(rect1.X, rect2.X) && DoubleUtil.AreClose(rect1.Y, rect2.Y) && DoubleUtil.AreClose(rect1.Height, rect2.Height) && DoubleUtil.AreClose(rect1.Width, rect2.Width);
    }
    public static bool IsBetweenZeroAndOne(double val)
    {
        return DoubleUtil.GreaterThanOrClose(val, 0.0) && DoubleUtil.LessThanOrClose(val, 1.0);
    }
    public static int DoubleToInt(double val)
    {
        if (0.0 >= val)
        {
            return (int)(val - 0.5);
        }
        return (int)(val + 0.5);
    }
    public static bool RectHasNaN(Rect r)
    {
        return DoubleUtil.IsNaN(r.X) || DoubleUtil.IsNaN(r.Y) || DoubleUtil.IsNaN(r.Height) || DoubleUtil.IsNaN(r.Width);
    }
    public static bool IsNaN(double value)
    {
        DoubleUtil.NanUnion nanUnion = default(DoubleUtil.NanUnion);
        nanUnion.DoubleValue = value;
        ulong num = nanUnion.UintValue & 18442240474082181120uL;
        ulong num2 = nanUnion.UintValue & 4503599627370495uL;
        return (num == 9218868437227405312uL || num == 18442240474082181120uL) && num2 != 0uL;
    }
}
```

Now we need just to define a couple of resources in the XAML (ILSpy again):

```
<Style x:Key="ToolbarThumb" TargetType="{x:Type Thumb}">
    <Setter Property="Control.Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Thumb}">
                <Border Padding="{TemplateBinding Control.Padding}" Background="#00FFFFFF" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                    <Rectangle>
                        <Rectangle.Fill>
                            <DrawingBrush Viewbox="0,0,4,4" Viewport="0,0,4,4" TileMode="Tile" ViewportUnits="Absolute" ViewboxUnits="Absolute">
                                <DrawingBrush.Drawing>
                                    <DrawingGroup>
                                        <DrawingGroup.Children>
                                            <GeometryDrawing Brush="#FFFFFFFF" Geometry="M1,1L1,3 3,3 3,1z" />
                                            <GeometryDrawing Brush="#A0A0A0" Geometry="M0,0L0,2 2,2 2,0z" />
                                        </DrawingGroup.Children>
                                    </DrawingGroup>
                                </DrawingBrush.Drawing>
                            </DrawingBrush>
                        </Rectangle.Fill>
                    </Rectangle>
                </Border>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="UIElement.IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="FrameworkElement.Cursor" Value="SizeAll" />
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
<Style x:Key="NoOverflowItems" TargetType="ToolBar" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type ToolBar}}">
    <Setter Property="Control.Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ToolBar}">
                <Grid Name="Grid" Margin="3,1,1,1" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                    <Border Name="MainPanelBorder" Background="{TemplateBinding Control.Background}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding Control.BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding Control.BorderThickness}" Padding="{TemplateBinding Control.Padding}">
                        <DockPanel KeyboardNavigation.TabIndex="1" KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation="Local">
                            <Thumb Name="ToolBarThumb" Style="{StaticResource ToolbarThumb}" Margin="-3,-1,0,0" Width="10" Padding="6,5,1,6" />
                            <ContentPresenter Name="ToolBarHeader" ContentSource="Header" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="4,0,4,0" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding UIElement.SnapsToDevicePixels}" />
                            <local:ToolBarPanel x:Name="PART_ToolBarPanel" IsItemsHost="True" Margin="0,1,2,2" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding UIElement.SnapsToDevicePixels}" />
                        </DockPanel>
                    </Border>
                </Grid>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Value="{x:Null}" Property="HeaderedItemsControl.Header">
                        <Setter TargetName="ToolBarHeader" Property="UIElement.Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="ToolBarTray.IsLocked" Value="True">
                        <Setter TargetName="ToolBarThumb" Property="UIElement.Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="ToolBar.Orientation" Value="Vertical">
                        <Setter TargetName="Grid" Property="FrameworkElement.Margin" Value="1,3,1,1" />
                        <Setter TargetName="ToolBarThumb" Property="FrameworkElement.Height" Value="10" />
                        <Setter TargetName="ToolBarThumb" Property="FrameworkElement.Width" Value="Auto" />
                        <Setter TargetName="ToolBarThumb" Property="FrameworkElement.Margin" Value="-1,-3,0,0" />
                        <Setter TargetName="ToolBarThumb" Property="Control.Padding" Value="5,6,6,1" />
                        <Setter TargetName="ToolBarHeader" Property="FrameworkElement.Margin" Value="0,0,0,4" />
                        <Setter TargetName="PART_ToolBarPanel" Property="FrameworkElement.Margin" Value="1,0,2,2" />
                        <Setter TargetName="ToolBarThumb" Property="DockPanel.Dock" Value="Top" />
                        <Setter TargetName="ToolBarHeader" Property="DockPanel.Dock" Value="Top" />

                        <Setter TargetName="MainPanelBorder" Property="FrameworkElement.Margin" Value="0,0,0,11" />
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="UIElement.IsEnabled" Value="False">
                        <Setter Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.GrayTextBrushKey}}" Property="Control.Foreground" />
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Now let's create a small Window (300x300) and add this XAML:

```
<ToolBarTray>
    <ToolBar OverflowMode="Never" Band="1">
        <Button Content="Button1" Width="76" Height="26" Margin="2" />
        <Button Content="Button2" Width="76" Height="26" Margin="2" />
        <Button Content="Button3" Width="76" Height="26" Margin="2" />
        <Button Content="Button4" Width="76" Height="26" Margin="2" />
        <Button Content="Button5" Width="76" Height="26" Margin="2" />
        <Button Content="Button6" Width="76" Height="26" Margin="2" />
    </ToolBar>
    <ToolBar Style="{StaticResource NoOverflowItems}" Band="2">
        <Button Content="ButtonA" Width="76" Height="26" Margin="2" />
        <Button Content="ButtonB" Width="76" Height="26" Margin="2" />
        <Button Content="ButtonC" Width="76" Height="26" Margin="2" />
        <Button Content="ButtonD" Width="76" Height="26" Margin="2" />
        <Button Content="ButtonF" Width="76" Height="26" Margin="2" />
        <Button Content="ButtonG" Width="76" Height="26" Margin="2" />
    </ToolBar>
</ToolBarTray>
```

I hope my code can help you.

Comment: First of all, thanks a lot for the very complex and detailed sample.

Comment: Unfortunately, that's not exactly what I was expecting. I was aiming for each independent toolbars to stay with the same physical size and appearance, but to change band inside the toobartray if the window size couldn't allow it, and not for the inside content of the toolbar to wrap. With your method it only works if each toolbar are alone in its horizontal band. When having multiple one next to another on the same band it only wrap one and hide the rest. In my application, I separate toolbars per functionality, but I want them to stay on the same band unless they don't fit.

Comment: For reference and better comprehension, here's what the application look on a 1080p display. I blurred the icons so that the application is not recognizable (it's a private corporation) http://i.imgur.com/tWz3Bgx.jpg . Multiple toolbar, on the same band, that can get too large on certain display.

Comment: Ok @Dunge, now I see what you need. I misunderstood your question. You wants that on window resizing, the toolbars move among the bands... Again I think this is possible, but this time I guess it is harder than with the wrappanel. Probably you should write your own version of ToolBarTray control.

Answer (score 1):

Four years after the original question, but if I understand the problem correctly it is possible by adding the ToolBar controls in a WrapPanel instead of a ToolBarTray. The downside is that the functionality of the ToolBarTray such as moving ToolBars within the tray is lost, but if that is not a problem it works well otherwise.